# Django receiver Column 'user_id' cannot be null

Tags: django, django-signals

I'm using [userena](http://www.django-userena.org/) receiver but I'm getting the following error...

**IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/
(1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")**

I'm assuming that I'm not accessing the user correctly in my own receivers.py. Could someone take a look?

Thanks

**receivers.py**

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from userena.signals import signup_complete

from accounts.models import Account

@receiver(signup_complete)
def handle_signup_complete(user, **kwargs):
    try:
        account = Account.objects.get(user=user)
    except Account.DoesNotExist:
        account = Account.objects.create()
        account.credit_limit = 0
        account.balance = 0
        account.user = user
        account.save()
```

**models.py**

```
class Account(models.Model):

    OPEN, FROZEN, CLOSED = 'Open', 'Frozen', 'Closed'
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=OPEN)
    credit_limit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1,
                                       null=True, blank=True)
    # For performance, we keep a cached balance
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1,
                                  null=True, blank=True)
    #FK
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

**userena signals.py**

```
from django.dispatch import Signal

signup_complete = Signal(providing_args=["user",])
activation_complete = Signal(providing_args=["user",])
confirmation_complete = Signal(providing_args=["user","old_email"])
password_complete = Signal(providing_args=["user",])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `create` wrong, you should pass the values as arguments to create. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create

```
@receiver(signup_complete)
def handle_signup_complete(user, **kwargs):
    try:
        account = Account.objects.get(user=user)
    except Account.DoesNotExist:
        account = Account.objects.create(
            user=user,
            credit_limit=0,
            balance=0,
        )
```

Basically, the problem is that any required fields need to be passed when creating the object.